# How to pull taxonomy fields

Tags: entities

I am trying to pull out a image field that is attached to a taxonomy term. I have tried using field_view_field with no luck. Does anyone have a good working example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this:

```
    $tid = $items[0]['tid'];
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    //it turn out that taxonomy_term_load gets empty array for my custom field
    //that's why  after some poking around Drupal API i come up with the following
    $term_page =  taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode = 'full');
    $term_url = taxonomy_term_uri($term);
    $image_url=$term_page['#term']->field_client_logo; //this is my custom field name
    $image = theme('image', array(
      'path' => $image_url['und'][0]['uri'],
      'alt' =>  $term->name,
      'title' => $object->title,
    ));
    return l($image, $term_url['path'] , array('html' => TRUE));
```